# Flutter SafeArea adds a white margin line on top of the screen

Tags: android, flutter

There is a thin white margin line on top of the screen.
How to fix this?

This bug occurs on the device (Nokia 7 Plus, screen size 2160x1080) but not on emulator.

(NB: If I switch SafeArea and Scaffold, I have a light status bar, which I don't want.)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/id/0/600'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you change it to Scaffold body then give Scaffold extendBodyBehindAppBar = true

Comment: @BurakAybi This does not work.